# Hello, who can help me with a time function in Pine Script?

Tags: time, pine-script, pause

In a strategy I want to avoid trading in several candles in a row. sell-buy-sell-buy,...
After a "strategy.close" I want to wait for at least 4 candles before a new "strategy.entry" takes place.
How can I create a pause between two strategies in Pine Script?

Answer (score 0):

You could add this condition:

```
farEnough = barssince(change(strategy.closedtrades)) > 4
```